# How will I use JDK 8 Optional utility class to handle Null Pointer Exception for collections?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, java-8

JDK 8 adds classes called ***Optional, OptionalDouble, OptionalInt, and OptionalLong*** that offer a way to handle situations in which a value may or may not be present. In the past, I would normally use the value ***null*** to indicate that no value is present. However, this can lead to ***null pointer exceptions*** if an attempt is made to ***dereference a null reference***. As a result, frequent checks for a null value were necessary to avoid generating an exception. These classes provide a better way to handle such situations.

The first and most general of these classes is Optional.

It is important to understand that ***an Optional instance*** can either contain a value of ***type T(bounded type) or be empty***. In other words, an Optional object does not necessarily contain a value.

```
Optional(value-based class) does not define any constructors, but it does define
several methods that let you work with Optional objects. For example, I can
determine if a value is present, obtain the value if it is present, obtain a 
default value when no value is present, and construct an Optional value.
```

I tried something like this,

```
    Optional<String> noVal = Optional.empty();
    Optional<String> hasVal = Optional.of("ABCDEFGH");;

    if(noVal.isPresent())
        System.out.println("This won't be displayed");
    else 
        System.out.println("noVal has no value");

    if(hasVal.isPresent())
        System.out.println(hasVal.get());

    String defStr = noVal.orElse("Default String");
    System.out.println(defStr);
```

But, i am unable to make out how to use it with collections so as to handle ***null***? Can someone.

Comment: I don't understand your question with regards to collections.

Comment: Would you like to validate null or empty Collections? I think that in that case you can use Collections API isEmpty() method

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks information about what you are actually going to do. Without a description of an operation, e.g. showing the code performing the action without using `Optional`, we can’t tell you how to do the same using `Optional` or whether this is possible at all.

One way of dealing with references which might be `null` is to construct an `Optional` via [`Optional.ofNullable(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-). This can also be used within an action that is applied to `Collection` elements:

```
    List<String> list=Arrays.asList("hello", null, "world", null);

    list.forEach(x->Optional.ofNullable(x).ifPresent(System.out::println));
```

However, most operations on collections which you want to formulate using new Java 8 features are good candidates for the stream API. While [`forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is suitable for a simple action, even the short detour via `Optional` makes it complex enough to benefit from the `Stream` API:

```
    list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(System.out::println);
```

does the same without nested operations.

So `Optional` is a good return type for a single element which might be absent, e.g. like for [`Stream.findAny`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--), but when processing collections, there are usually better alternatives.